# Remember form values when changing selected date

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form built in HTML that looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function previousWeek() {
            var dateStr = document.getElementById("my_date").value;
            var date = new Date(dateStr);
            var datePreviousWeek = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getUTCDate() - 7);
            document.getElementById("my_date").value = datePreviousWeek.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        }

        function nextWeek() {
            var dateStr = document.getElementById("my_date").value;
            var date = new Date(dateStr);
            var datePreviousWeek = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + 7);
            document.getElementById("my_date").value = datePreviousWeek.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .table {
            display: table;
        }
        .row {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .cell {
            display: table-cell;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Availability Form</p>
<button onclick="previousWeek()">Previous Week</button>
<input type="date" id="my_date" />    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var now = new Date();
    var daysUntilNextMonday = 7 - now.getDay() + 1;
    var nextMonday = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + daysUntilNextMonday);
    document.getElementById("my_date").value = nextMonday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
</script>
<button onclick="nextWeek()">Next Week</button>
    <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwVQja_SD4DTraHTWKH3rH81bveoIOB38U8PiSqiog/dev" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">Available</div>
                    <div class="cell">Unavailable</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="monday" value="available"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="monday" value="unavailable"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="tuesday" value="available"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="tuesday" value="unavailable"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="wednesday" value="available"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="wednesday" value="unavailable"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="thursday" value="available"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="thursday" value="unavailable"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="friday" value="available"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <input type="radio" name="friday" value="unavailable"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is when the user hits the 'Next week' or 'Previous Week' buttons I need to clear out the current radio button selection (not a big issue).  However, when they go back to a week that they've already entered, I need to remember what they've already entered.  Additionally I need to send ALL data (not just the displayed week) in a POST request to my REST API.

I cannot find a clean way to remember this data without POSTing it to the server when the user changes weeks (which I don't want to do).

Thanks!

Comment: just store a hashmap (or Object) that maps each date to the form data for that date. When the user navigates to a new date, save the form fields as key/value pairs for that date. Then if they go back to the given date, just fetch the form values from the Object and fill in the fields.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define on what events your data considered changed and needs to be saved. Is it on form inputs keyup event or change event?
2. Just use a variable to save that state data. That will be like:
   `var state = [
   {date: *somedate*, email: *someEmail*, name: *someName*, surname: *someSurname*},
   {date: *someOtherDate*, email: *someEmail*, name: *someName*, surname: *someSurname*},
   ];`

At the end you can send `state` object as a post data and all data you will have.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solution helps you out.

```
var weekOfYear = function(date){
   var d = new Date(+date);
   d.setHours(0,0,0);
   d.setDate(d.getDate()+4-(d.getDay()||7));
   return Math.ceil((((d-new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1))/8.64e7)+1)/7);
};
```

call this function in previousWeek, nextWeek and onchange of input. Store the week the user navigated to, in an array along with the data of the available and unavailable radio buttons. Store 0 for unavailable and 1 for available in an array corresponding to the days of the week. So your array will have seven values.

For instance,

Say the user has navigated to 33rd and 34th week of the year, store it like,

```
[
   {33, [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]},
   {34, [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]} 
]
```

Now, when you call weekOfYear function, do call another function to check your stored values in the array for the week. If the week number is present in your stored array, populate the radio buttons.